# Casting text to dates in postgres where precision changes

Tags: postgresql

I have a text column which records dates in varying precision.

```
12/07/1951
--/06/1976
```

I want to move them to a postgres date type column. I can use `to_date()` when I know the composition of the source data. Is there a clever way to do this?

Comment: Getting somewhere by using like query on the source
WHERE worth.da not like '%--%' to catch dates with full values.

Comment: Are those two rows in your dataset? What would be the rule for that `--/06/1976` to replace -- with 01?